# Completely Centering text in Circular link

Tags: html, css

I've read related answers on the site regarding this topic. I did end up being able to center it by decreasing the font size, however, it left me with small text and a large circle.

Here it is:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="circle"><a href="index.html">About</a>

        </li>
        <li class="circle"><a href="coding.html">Coding</a>

        </li>
        <li class="circle"><a href="health.html">Health</a>

        </li>
        <li class="circle"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 7px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/theskinnyreader/c3evfj5b/

I would like to know how I can center text of the size in my code below and keep the size of the circle to a minimum.

CSS

```
.circle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/theskinnyreader/fdu1dqko/

Comment: [something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/tfrLgtdf/)

Comment: Yeah, like that, except with a smaller circle that hugs the text pretty nicely. Frankly, I'm not even sure if it's possible with just CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

What changed here is i made the .circle have a relative position so that the text in the  tag can have an absolute position. Then pace the anchor at 50% of top and 50% of left and translate it back 50% and up 50%. I only added the -webkit-transform because my browser is chrome but you should add one with -moz-, -ms-, and -o- as well

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    10px;
    padding: 0;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 3%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.circle {
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use the transform property? 

Setting the top and left properties to 50% is not enough?

Comment: @Edson that wouldn't be enough, the top and left properties will place the top-left corner of the <a> tag in the center of the circle. The transform will then move it 50% to the left and up in order to get the center of the <a> tag to the center of the circle. Does that make sense?

Comment: Aha! Makes sense now. I had put the code above into my CSS file w/o using the .circle a part, and what you just described would happen did happen. Now I understand why. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it!